# Expected type 'None' got 'str' instead python

Tags: python

[ERROR MSG PYCHARM SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCQlM.png)

I've written a date parser function that expects four arguments and outputs a dictionary. The first one is an expected list (e.g.[1996 - 2020]) while the other three arguments are the separate lists containing stopwords.

I keep on receiving "Expected type 'None', got str instead warnings for 10 lines anywhere I used this line of code example:
''.join(var[-1] or
' '.join(var_two[:-1])
output datatypes: are **STRING** and/or **LIST**

More specifically:
Example:

```
start_year_issue = ''.join(no_symbol_start[-1])
start_month_issue = ' '.join(no_symbol_start[:-1])
```

output:

```
<type, str> 2018
<type, list> ['Feb']
```

Otherwise, the function works.

FULL CODE:

**1.List of stop words (as aforementioned 4 arguments for parse())**

```
import re


# "Present" word in all  language combination
pres_ = ["současnost", "I dag", "Heute", "Present", "actualidad", "aujourd’hui", "वर्तमान", "Saat ini",
         "Presente", "現在", "현재", "Kini", "heden", "Nå", "obecnie", "o momento", "Prezent",
         "настоящее время", "nu", "ปัจจุบัน ", "Kasalukuyan", "Halen", "至今", "現在"]
```

**2. Function that splits the input list to dictionary start and end date**

```
def raw_start_end_date_extractor(scraped_date: list) -> dict:
    merge_split_dates = {"Start_date_raw": None, "End_date_raw": None}
```

The output of second function solely. (even though it is used in the third function parse())

```
raw_start_end_date_extractor(["Issued Feb 2018 · No Expiration Date"])

{'Start_date_raw': 'Issued Feb 2018', 'End_date_raw': 'No Expiration Date'}
```

**3. MAIN Final Function is parse() function that uses the above **lists** and **raw_start_end_date_extractor** function to further YEAR and MONTH start and end dates.**

```
def parse(scraped_date: list, list_issue: list, list_pres: list, list_expire: list, list_no_exp: list) -> dict:
    """
    scraped_date: ['1996 - 2002']
    list_issue:  issue_


    None - no data
    '1' - ongoing date
    '0' - not ongoing date

    Fields from LinkedIn that parse() works for: Experience, Education, Licences & certifications
    """
    container = {'start_date_year': None, 'start_date_month': None, 'end_date_year': None,
                 'end_date_month': None, 'is_ongoing_date': None}
    flag_expired = False
    flag_issued = False
    save_stop_word = []
    for key in raw_start_end_date_extractor(scraped_date):
        if key.startswith('Start'):
            if ':' or '.' or ',' in
```

**Output as it should be:**

```
parse(['Issued Feb 2018 · No Expiration Date'], issue_, pres_, expire_, no_exp_)

{'start_date_year': '2018', 'start_date_month': 'Feb', 'end_date_year': None, 'end_date_month': None, 'is_ongoing_date': '1'}
```

**Summary: so the issue is with  all variables where I used join function (''.join(variable[-1]) or ''.join(variabletwo[:-1])
Specifically  WARNING occurs on the lines where I want to add to the dictionary named CONTAINER that has predefined None values by default**

**Example:**

```
container = {'start_date_year': None, 'start_date_month': None, 'end_date_year': None,
                 'end_date_month': None, 'is_ongoing_date': None}
```

```
start_year_issue = ''.join(no_symbol_start[-1])
start_month_issue = ' '.join(no_symbol_start[:-1])
```

**Their output** is a **string**: **2018** and **list**: **['Feb']**
no_symbol_start[-1]

```
2018
```

no_symbol_start[:-1]

```
['Feb']
```

**warning at:**

```
container['start_date_month'] = start_month_issue
container['start_date_year'] = start_year_issue
```

start_date_month

```
'2018'
```

start_date_year

```
'Feb'
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback.

Comment: That isn't an error, it's just PyCharm being stupid.

Comment: Is your program running. I mean is this an error message after running the program or just a warning.

Comment: Where did `container['start_date_month']` *first* get assigned? This looks like the static type checker inferred its type to be `None`, but then you tried to assign a string value. This would not be a run-time error, since Python itself has no problem with a variable being assigned a value of any type at any time.

Comment: Please check the updated post, I've posted the whole code with the final output.

Comment: Don't. Instead, reduce it to a [mcve] which you can then post here.

Comment: Please check my post now

Comment: @Irfanwani  it is warning not error, the program is running as you can see the output

Comment: @interjay that's what I thought as well, but maybe I'm making some mistake somewhere?!

Comment: @9769953 I've provided you step by step tracebacks

Comment: @Adrian023 then ignore it.it is just the formatter giving warning which is not always right